# How to gain control over exception logging in Wildfly?

Tags: jsf, exception, wildfly, error-logging, omnifaces

I am using `Wildfly 10` with `Omnifaces 2.6`

I learned to use the [FullAjaxExceptionHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) to handle AjaxExceptions

and the [FacesExceptionFilter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/FacesExceptionFilter)  for Exceptions caused by normal get Requests.

The Handler and the Filter work fine. The only trouble is the logging output.

Exceptions caught by the `FacesExceptionFilter` will always log twice with the categories
`javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application` and `io.undertow.request`

Exceptions caught by the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` will log additionaly as warning in the category `javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle`

I would like to switch off that additional logging of Exceptions that are caused by the users browser.

I could silence the logger by setting those categories to level "NONE", but I dont think thats the right thing to do, because I could also accidentally ignore other, really important messages.

Is there a way to tell Wildfly not to do additional logging of Exceptions caused by the users browser?

Comment: I wouldn't bother. The effort required to reliably log exception only once is too much.

Comment: I just got the idea to redirect those categories to an additional file - so the normal log will look clean, but the original output is still available.